# Django Field with default value as stored procedure call

Tags: django, stored-procedures, django-models

I'm trying to create a Django Field that when it builds the SQL to create the table the DEFAULT value needs to be a call to stored procedure (postgres).

Example:

```
foo INT DEFAULT my_stored_proc()
```

I will build a custom Field class if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

(I haven't done before but I would do it) If the store procedure return a value then you could do:

1. Create a normal field, setting the field type as the expected by the stored procedure
2. Use *setter* and *getter* to access the field created. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1684851/394647)
3. Put your stored procedure call inside the *setter* and *getter* like this [example](http://goo.gl/RzD6o)

I hope this works ...

Comment: Well, I need it to be the DEFAULT so when a row is inserted that value is created by the stored procedure at the same time by Postgres. It's important because it also happens to be the primary key.

Comment: What about set default as blank=True (to avoid being required on submit) and override the save method of the model to call the stored procedure and set the value you want. Would that make sense for you?

Comment: chachan, sorry that doesn't make sense to me.