# Python typing support for not-None "late" variables

Tags: python, typing

Dart has "[late variables](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables)" , swift has "[Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals)".

Does Python have something equivalent?

That means, something like `myvar: Late[str] = None` that would indicate that I know that all access to myvar later on will be after it is initialized to a non-None value.

My use case:

```
@dataclass
class Flag:
    name: Optional[str] = dataclasses.field(init=False, default=None)
    default_value: Any
    value_type: Type
    description: str = ""
```

Flag.name is initialized by a "friend" class, and all access to Flag is through that friend class, so sure that outside of this module all access is not to an Optional, but to an actual str.

Comment: Python variables cannot be uninitialized because they are created by initialization. If a variable exists, it has a none-None value, unless you explicitly set it to None.

Comment: Do you mean like https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html? It's not a general attribute you would apply to any type, but a type in and of itself (values of which can produce values of other types).

Comment: Best that I have found is something like `typing.cast(myvar, str)` at the place where `myvar` is declared.

Comment: Or just that `myvar` will be a string once I assign to it? Given that Python doesn't require variables to be declared, `myvar: str` is sufficient. You don't have to initialize the variable first.

Comment: python typing support only supports ahead of time static type checking. there is not much sense in telling it that it will eventually be correct at runtime.

Comment: Twisted offers [deferreds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.4.1/core/howto/defer-intro.html)

Comment: I added a code example that clarifies the problem

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't have declarations, only definitions. You can write something like

```
# *Looks* like a declaration, but does not create a variable
# named myvar, only annotates the name.
myvar: str
```

which tells any static type checker that `myvar`, when finally used, will have a `str` value, but doesn't actually create the variable yet. The annotation itself has no meaning at runtime, aside from possibly updating the global `__annotations__` dict.

Later on, an initial assignment like `myvar = "foo"` will be accepted by a static type checker, but an initial assignment like `myvar = 1` will be rejected.

---

Such non-assigned annotated names are rarely *necessary* in Python. Their biggest use is in the body of a `class` statement decorated by `dataclass`, which allows you to define the instance attributes for instances of the class. (This information gets used when generating methods like `__init__`.)

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
     x: int
     y: str = "foo"
     z = 3
```

The type itself isn't terribly important; it's the *presence* of a type that causes `dataclass` to generate an `__init__` method like

```
def __init__(self, x: int, y: str = "foo"):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

The unannotated name `z` is taken as an ordinary class attribute.

Comment: I think it would be good to say that in Python there _usually_ isn't a reason to annotate a variable, but especially not before it's defined.  That being said, it can be helpful in less common situations that mypy struggles with.

Comment: This is problematic because if I were to do 

    @dataclass
    class Flag:
        name: str = dataclasses.field(init=False, default=None)

The type checker would complain that the default value is not compatible with the type.

Comment: Well, yes. If you are explicitly saying the default can by `None`, then `str` is the wrong type. Either use `Optional[str]`, or provide a default string value (like `""`). If you want to say that the field *has* no default value (i.e., it's required), the correct sentinel is `dataclasses.MISSING`, not `None`. (And `MISSING` is the default default when no explicit default is provided.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the following not-the-best solution. I made the relevant member "protected" - changed it to _name, and wrapped it with a property.

The runtime check is only there to quiet down the type checker without shutting it down, and it does afford a little bit of extra protection if someone does misuse this, at a relatively small runtime speed code (that I don't care to optimize right now).

```
@dataclass
class Flag:
    _name: Optional[str] = dataclasses.field(init=False, default=None)
    default_value: Any
    value_type: Type
    description: str = ""

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        if self._name is None:
            raise RuntimeError("self._name not initialized")
        return self._name
```

Comment: makes sense - you probably also want to provide [@name.setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684828/how-to-set-attributes-using-property-decorators) too!

Comment: An easy way to reduce the runtime cost of this is by adding the `@functools.cache` decorator in between the `@property` decorator and the function definition.

Answer (score -2):

You can `await` [awaitable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable), allowing another coroutine to run

```py
async def my_funcion(*args):
    ...

value = await my_function(*args)
```